# What is the name of a G major triad in the context of F sharp major?

Tags: chords

G major triad is composed of G, B, D. If we're in the context of F sharp major, what is the name of the G major triad? I know it's not a 2 chord since in the context of F sharp major, 2 is G sharp, not G.
Thanks!

Comment: It may have various functions depending on the context. Please provide full chord progression.

Comment: @user1079505 It's the first verse of the Coldplay song, "Daylight". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSz8iqz2zbU

Comment: @LudwigGershwin Can you create or find a chord chart? Questions that require transcription from a recording are off topic.

Comment: G major has the same relationship to and functions in F sharp major that D flat major has in C major.  The nomenclature can vary somewhat.

Answer (score 3):

A G major chord does not exist in the key of F# diatonically but if you expand into chromaticism the major chord built on the lowered 2nd degree (G in F# major) is referred to as a Neapolitan chord. This chord actually exists as a II chord in the Phrygian mode and can also be referred to as a Phrygian II chord. It can be analyzed as a chord borrowed from the Phrygian mode or modal interchange.

It is often associated with Flamenco music and other Spanish styles but it is universally used in many styles of music. It sometimes is played as a major 7th which then shares a common tone with the tonic chord.

It is commonly written about in harmony texts. This Wikipedia article has some interesting information about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neapolitan_chord

Comment: PLEASE stop with this 'borrowing' nonsense!  Yes, bII is diatonic in other keys and modes.  So what?  We're interested in its position as a chromatic chord in the current key.

Comment: @Laurence You don’t like using the term borrowing, we get it. We got it when you mentioned it 10 times before. Regardless of your personal preferences that is a legitimate explanation for where it comes from so get used to continuing to see it.

Comment: And I shall continue to preach the truth whenever this new-fangled 'borrowing' idea comes up! My problem with 'borrowing' is that it DOESN'T explain anything.  It's a cop-out of trying to explain.

Comment: @Laurence I won’t get in the way or your quest for truth but IMO it does explain by showing a likely source for where the use of a non-diatonic chord might have come from. After all, chords like a bIII and bVII in a major key are pretty obviously from the minor tonality.

Comment: But so what?   Any chromatic chord is probably going to be diatonic in some other key.  Unless it's being used as a gateway to that key, so what?

Comment: @Laurence It doesn’t have to be a gateway. A chromatic chord that is diatonic in a parallel key can imply the tonality of the other key and add richness and complexity to the harmony.

Comment: Or it can just be a chromatic chord, adding a certain colour to the base key.  Why are people so frightened of this idea, that it may just NOT BE DIATONIC!

Comment: @Laurence Which people? Certainly not me, I’m largely a jazz musician by trade. I won’t use the “B” word but I think the concept of modal interchange is valuable to people who are starting to learn the complexities of harmony. Once you know something you know it. I don’t think about the IV7 chord I used as coming from the Dorian mode but initially it helps to have an understanding about where some common chromatic chords come from.

Answer (score 2):

A G major chord in an F sharp major context would be called a **Neapolitan chord**. The Neapolitan chord is normally notated as ♭II, sometimes even if its root note would be notated with a natural instead of a sharp (such as this case here).

Comment: When would the root of the Neapolitan chord be written with a sharp?

Comment: @phoog - Only either if the tonic of the current key is a double sharp or the composer/editor just wants to be funny (e.g. opts to notate a B flat major chord in A major as an A sharp major chord instead because "the key signature has sharps in it").

Answer (score -1):

It's ♭II.

In classical harmony it's a Neapolitan chord.

In jazz harmony it can be a ♭5 substitution for V.

A deleted answer led with 'There is no G Major chord in F# Major.' This is a common view which deserves to be examined.   True, a G major chord is not made from the notes of the F♯ major scale. It is not diatonic in F♯ major. But chromatic chords are allowed!  And they can exist simply AS chromatic chords, not necessarily as a gateway to a different key.  Sometimes 'borrowing' is a useful concept.  Often it's unnecessary.  '♭II' is an honourable title, it doesn't have to be excused as a loan from some other key in which it is diatonic.

I've spent years pushing this mantra: 'Theory describes, it doesn't command'.   Maybe add another one: 'Notes outside the scale do not necessarily affect the tonality'. It's a quote from *Walter Piston, Harmony.*